# Alpha channel node settings affecting every single alpha channel in project

Tags: texturing

I'm running Blender 3.5, and I'm porting a map from MGS1 into Blender. Anyway, when I change the clip threshold, or really any node setting for one of my alpha channels, it affects EVERY SINGLE other alpha channel in the scene. All the materials are separate materials with different names, and I just have no clue why this is happening. One possible idea I have, is that maybe the "active_material" thing that runs everytime you change the clip threshold is broken, that every material counts as active_material?

[image]
[image]
[image]